# difference between removeobject and removeobjectatindex?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I was just wondering what the difference is between removeobject and removeobjectatindex. I understand that removeobjectatindex removes the object at a specific index of an array, but what i dont understand is what removeobject does.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is clearly  answered in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObject:)

Answer (score 2):

`-removeObject:` takes the object you want to remove from the collection as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

**removeObject**  removes all occurrences of that object from the array . 
   Remove object method internally uses two method .  It uses indexOfObject: two locate the indexes of the given object. and then  it use removeObjectAtIndex: method two simply remove that objects . This method is useful when you want two remove more than one similar objects  otherwise you can use removeObjectAtIndex:  method directly .

Answer (score 0):

The `removeObjectAtIndex` method will only remove **one** object from the array (at the index you specify).

The `removeObject` method will remove all objects that pass the `isEqual` test. That means that potentially many objects will be removed.  It also means that an object you expect to be removed, may not be, depending on how `isEqual` is implemented.  By default, the `isEqual` method just compares pointers (two objects are equal if they have the same address).  Some classes, e.g. NSString, override `isEqual` to do a higher level comparison. So the `removeObject` can seem a little temperamental at times.

From the class reference for `removeObject`

> This method uses indexOfObject: to locate matches and then removes them by using removeObjectAtIndex:. Thus, matches are determined on the basis of an object’s response to the isEqual: message. If the array does not contain anObject, the method has no effect (although it does incur the overhead of searching the contents).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *a=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"4",@"5",@"sad", nil];
[a removeObject:@"4"]; // here it will check whether array contains a variable 4 in the array if array has it it will remove that object.
NSLog(@"%@",a);

[a removeObjectAtIndex:0]; // this will remove object at index 0
NSLog(@"%@",a);

[a removeAllObjects]; // this will remove all objects in array
NSLog(@"%@",a);
```